# Creating a log for a powershell command

Tags: powershell

I have a simple command to create a CSV file in powershell.  Is there a way to log this information separate from the file?  I will be needing to manipulate the CSV file, so I don't want to rely on it being my only way of logging the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can also export the output of commands by using the `>` and `>>` operators.

example:
You can write all of the Adobe services and their information to a file with this code:

```
get-service -DisplayName Adobe* > C:\services.txt
```

if you wanted to append to that with Windows services:

```
get-service -DisplayName Windows* >> C:\services.txt
```

so if you wanted to export your CSV to a file you can easily do so by adding a `>` at the end of the command pointing to the filename you wish to export it to:

```
> C:\Log_$date.csv
```

and if you ever needed to append more logs you can simply do so by using the `>>`

```
>> C:\Log_$date.csv
```

if you use `>` it will overwrite and existing data in the file with new data. `>>` appends.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a log for people who are in charge of the production you can add your own application log using dedicated Cmdlets. A the moment I create and use one PowerShell log for all my scripts to publish details of the execution (information) and errors (in coordination with good exception handling) for people who are in charge of the production. You can dedicate a log for one script (as it exists a log for DNS etc.)

Here is an example :

```
# List of logs
Get-EventLog -list

# Creating your own log
New-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting" -Source "MaSource"

# List of logs
Get-EventLog -list

# Writting in your own log
Write-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting" -EventId 12 `
               -Message "Mon Message" 
               -Source "MaSource" -EntryType Warning

# Reading in your own log
Get-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting"  

# Suppressing your log
Remove-EventLog -LogName "SlxScripting"
```